# MySQL ranking system custom query

Tags: mysql, ranking

I have ranking system, which is result based on points.

```
    User | Points
    1    | 100
    2    | 197
    3    | 123
    4    | 174
    5    | 98
    ...
   197   | 21
   198   | 110
   199   | 154
```

Assuming that my user-id is 197, so first I want to know my rank based or points, highest points at first, lowest at last, so here assume that my rank (user-id = 197) is #150

After getting my rank (if my rank is not in top 100 list) then I want to get list of 100 users where in, I need to get 1st to 50th rank users + 125th to 175th rank users so I can get my rank in this list too, but for list ranks will be actual ranks in results

```
User | Points | Rank
18    | 199   | 1
22    | 198   | 2
31    | 180   | 3
19    | 174   | 4
51    | 168   | 5
+
17    | 22    | 149
197   | 21    | 150
199   | 14    | 151
```

I have app in PHP, so what is best and efficient way to achieve this result set?

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overall query for returning scores with their rank would be (or should I say 'could be', as it works but might not be the most elegant solution):

```
SET @count = 0; 
SELECT 
  user, 
  points, 
  rank 
    FROM( 
        SELECT user,
                 points, 
                    @count := @count + 1 'rank' 
         FROM scores 
         ORDER BY points DESC 
    ) as ranks;
```

So if you wanted to know the rank of a specific user, you'd add a `where` clause at the end, of:

```
 WHERE user = 197;
```

When it comes to the second part, especially with the formatting, I think that's best done in PHP.  You could run the above to obtain your 'rank', then do something like this (note: I'm just pseudo quoting PHP here, rather than scripting an answer):

```
$myRank = [result of above query];

if($myRank > 100) {

// retrieve first 50 results and display in query 1

echo "..."; // or in a <td>, etc.

// retrieve results x to y and display in query2, loop through a table etc.

}
else {

// retrieve the first 100 if your score is in that range

}
```

The SQL for the first 50 results would be

```
SET @count = 0; 
SELECT 
  user, 
  points, 
  rank 
    FROM( 
        SELECT user,
                 points, 
                    @count := @count + 1 'rank' 
         FROM scores 
         ORDER BY points DESC 
    ) as ranks
    LIMIT 0,50;
```

and then you'd have to use the output of our theoretical `$myRank` in php to obtain the next set of results.  For example, if you wanted the next 50 after your rank, you'd change the last line to:

```
LIMIT $myRank,$upper;
```

where upper would be, in php:

```
$upper = $myRank+50;
```

You'd obviously need to figure out exactly what you want to achieve in terms of different scenarios before you could really tie down a complete solution, but hopefully this is of some help.